# Snap to Grid in jsplumb

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm using [jsplumb](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/demo/home/jquery.html). How can I make the draggable elements snap to the grid? I have a grid as an image, where the boxes are the same size of the draggable elements.

here is the code Im using to control the movement of the object to the grid

```
instance.draggable(jsPlumb.getSelector(".flowchart-demo .record"), { grid: [1, 1] });
```

Comment: Adding some code that you was trying to solve your problem with might give more interest to people who might gift you an answer.

Answer (score 1):

try increasing the grid .

I use instance.draggable($('#flowchartWindowNextLevel'),{containment:"parent", grid: [20, 20]}); But for better snapping you can use 40,40

Comment: I tried using the same solution however it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons (I dont know. You should ask JSPlump author), it's working perfect with option `grid: [10, 10]`